# How to create my custom MembershipProvider in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, membership-provider

I have my own tables for the users in my database. They're called `Teachers` and `Students`. I was testing ASP.NET MVC4 SimpleMembership but I guess I need to create a new membership provider.

Each table has its own password field (plain text)

[image]

Here's the image of my design. I would like to know if this is a good way to login and identify which user type (student or teacher) is logging or can I simplify this just using one table called Users and not to implement my own custom membership (using default UserProfile)

Comment: why can't you use simple membership? You can have your own table

Comment: Can you show me an example? Until I know, simple membership only use one table called UserProfiles and I need to extend two types of user (Student and Teacher)

Comment: SimpleMembership doesn't constrain you to any profile setup, there's really no profile setup. Simply create your profile info after your user is created so you have the primary key of your user. That's the easier part of simple membership, you can just be kn control of your data again- so yes - it's just another table you can read using say entity framework once your user logs in.

Answer (score 2):

Normally when designing a membership system, you start with a base `users` table. Then from there, you could have `user_types` (which may be Students, Teachers, or anything else in the future like Parents). In your application, you can then test to see which type of user is logging in and respond accordingly.

If you need to store additional data for a specific user type, for example teachers, then you can create a table that adds on to the base `users` table, and replicate this in your models by having a `Teacher` model extend the base `User` model, adding any teacher-specific logic you may need.

Comment: Thanks for your response, so I'm not get lost. So do you recommend to have in a common table called User_Profile (Id, FullName), Password would be manage by Membership. If I need more specific logic for students by example, that entity needs Class Id, so I reference Class with Student, right?

Comment: Another question, what would you suggest to replicate. That part I have so many doubts.

Answer (score 0):

please go through below links... may be this helps...  :)

http://www.bradygaster.com/custom-authentication-with-mvc-3.0

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers

[Custom membership provider and role provider](http://www.mattwrock.com/post/2009/10/14/Implementing-custom-Membership-Provider-and-Role-Provider-for-Authinticating-ASPNET-MVC-Applications.aspx)